# DirectX: Draw bitmap image scale up in viewport caused low quality?

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, direct3d11

I'm using DirectX to draw the images with RGB data in buffer. The fllowing is sumary code:

```
    // create the vertex buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;                // write access access by CPU and GPU
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeOfOurVertices;             // size is the VERTEX struct * pW*pH
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;       // use as a vertex buffer
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;    // allow CPU to write in buffer
    dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pVBuffer);       // create the buffer

    //Create Sample for texture
    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC desc;
    desc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_ANISOTROPIC;
    desc.MaxAnisotropy = 16;
    ID3D11SamplerState *ppSamplerState = NULL;
    dev->CreateSamplerState(&desc, &ppSamplerState);
    devcon->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &ppSamplerState);

//Create list vertices from RGB data buffer
    pW = bitmapSource->PixelWidth;
    pH = bitmapSource->PixelHeight;
    OurVertices = new VERTEX[pW*pH];    
    vIndex = 0;
    unsigned char* curP = rgbPixelsBuff;
    for (y = 0; y < pH; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < pW; x++)
        {
            OurVertices[vIndex].Color.b = *curP++;
            OurVertices[vIndex].Color.g = *curP++;
            OurVertices[vIndex].Color.r = *curP++;
            OurVertices[vIndex].Color.a = *curP++;
            OurVertices[vIndex].X = x;
            OurVertices[vIndex].Y = y;
            OurVertices[vIndex].Z = 0.0f;
            vIndex++;
        }
    }
    sizeOfOurVertices = sizeof(VERTEX)* pW*pH;

    // copy the vertices into the buffer
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
    devcon->Map(pVBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);    // map the buffer
    memcpy(ms.pData, OurVertices, sizeOfOurVertices);                 // copy the data
    devcon->Unmap(pVBuffer, NULL);     
    // unmap the buffer

    // clear the back buffer to a deep blue
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f));

    // select which vertex buffer to display
    UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
    UINT offset = 0;
    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    // select which primtive type we are using
    devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINTLIST);

    // draw the vertex buffer to the back buffer
    devcon->Draw(pW*pH, 0);

    // switch the back buffer and the front buffer
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
```

When the viewport's size is smaller or equal the image's size => everything is ok. But when viewport's size is lager image's size => the image's quality is very bad.

I've searched and tried to use `desc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_ANISOTROPIC;`as above code (I've tried to use `D3D11_FILTER_MIN_POINT_MAG_MIP_LINEAR` or `D3D11_FILTER_MIN_LINEAR_MAG_MIP_POINT`too), but the result is not better. The following images are result of displaying:

[image]
Someone can tell me the way to fix it.

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the scaling value? It's obvious, if you upscale an image then it will look blurry. You might want to use mipmaps instead?

Comment: @Asesh: I tried to use D3D11_FILTER_MIN_POINT_MAG_MIP_LINEAR or D3D11_FILTER_MIN_LINEAR_MAG_MIP_POINT too, but it is not better. The scaling value are 1.2, 1.5 or any values, they always make the image occur cross lines as above images. It doesn't look the blurry as normally.

Comment: Does your texture support mipmaps? DDS files support mipmaps. Just using that filter won't suffice, your texture should support mipmaps too or you will have to generate them at runtime. Anyways, there shouldn't be so much difference as seen in the screenshots with those scaling values that you have used. There must be something wrong.

Comment: Can you explain more detail for me. I'm a newbie with directX.
I really don't understand much what you said. Thank you!

Comment: This tutorial uses mipmaps generated at runtime: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11s2tut05.html. Just search for mipmap and try to understand it. Anyways, looking at the second image, am sure mipmap won't solve this issue cause like I said those scaling values shouldn't make so much difference. You should debug your shader.

Comment: I will read your link and try. Thank you!

Comment: Like I said, mipmap won't solve this issue. Something else is the culprit. You should debug your shader and compare the output

Comment: @TTGroup You are drawing each pixel as a point using DirectX. It is normal that when the screen size gets bigger, your points will move apart and the quality will be bad. You should draw a textured quad instead, using a texture that you fill with your RGB data and a pixel shader.

Comment: @VuVirt: That is exactly problem, I tried to use the textured, and it worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing each pixel as a point using DirectX. It is normal that when the screen size gets bigger, your points will move apart and the quality will be bad. You should draw a textured quad instead, using a texture that you fill with your RGB data and a pixel shader.